# siri shortcuts - get key of selected dictionary value

Tags: sirishortcuts

I have this json format of an array:

```
{"key_0":"myValue_0","key_1":"myValue_1"}
```

With this I created a dictionary, which shows me the results like this:

[image]

Now I would like to know the key of of the selected dictionary entry.
But I have only this options:

Get:

- value
- all keys
- all values

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how to get a key from a dictionary:**

```
Dictionary {'gredgdsg':'fgdsdfg', 'afgfds':12313}

Get [Item] from (Dictionary:Keys)
```

The way this works is, when you set the Dictionary method to 'Keys', it returns it as a list. So, from there, you can use a Get Item from List block to choose a key.

Hers an image example:
[you will have to click this link to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv0je.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Get Name" action on the Chosen Item, and you'll get the dictionary key.